# Creating service which even runs during windows user is logged off

Tags: windows, service, vb6

I have my own vb6 application which i used by lot of customers .I already have an update.exe with my application which checks for updates and installs it if available.The checking for updates is done during opening and closing of software. This update.exe is also a small vb6 application which we run by calling it from our Main application.

Now we have requirement where if a user is logged off then also we need to check for updates and install it.I think it can be done by creating service which runs continuously.
Now how to create a service which runs my update.exe continuously even when user is logged off?

Comment: Why not compile your vb6 application to run as a Windows NT Service using ntsvc.ocx. Just to add, Microsoft does not support this but its worth checking first and make judgement call.
Check this [site](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=92) for how to do this.

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover yes. By using SrvAny and INSTSRV.EXE i was able to create service.But while service is running in task manager process tab i can see SRVANY.exe running. Is this the only way to run service?

Comment: @ITresearcher: Using SVRANY is the way that I do it for my VB6 apps.  Seeing your programmig running in task manager under the process tab is normal.  In fact many of those programs in the tab are services.